# How to authenticate `couchdb` when connecting to it from `pouchdb` in nodejs?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

CouchDB is running in the server and I am using `pouchdb` in a nodejs. I have trouble to connecting to CouchDB and I always got 401 Unauthorized error. Below is the code I am using:

```
const db = new PouchDB(url, {
    ajax: {
      withCredentials: false,
      headers: {
        authorization: 'signed 4252342xxxx ...',
      }
    }
  });
```

The error I got is: `{ message: 'Unauthorized', status: 401, name: 'unknown' }`

Is it the correct way to do authentication?

Comment: Are you able to connect to CouchDB using *curl*?   Could you show an example of the command syntax you use?

Comment: AFAIK, the options/method you're using don't exist in vanilla pouchdb

edit: https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As M-I pointed out, your method of getting the database does not match the [PouchDB API](https://pouchdb.com/api.html). This is the example from the manual that shows how to add headers to the request:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://example.com/dbname', {
  fetch: function (url, opts) {
    opts.headers.set('X-Some-Special-Header', 'foo');
    return PouchDB.fetch(url, opts);
  }
});
```

You do not seem to be using username/password, but if you are the "auth" option can be added to the options parameter.